# Saleable quantity is empty even though quantity is showing admin

Tags: stock, inventory, quantity, multi-source-inventory

Right, here is a strange one
we are using magento 2.4.2 and stock in the channel to import product data (if any one is aware of them) for some strange range we ever we ever we run the import the "saleable quantity" shows empty in admin.
[image: saleable quantity empty]
we can fix this by running `INSERT IGNORE INTO` inventory_source_item `(source_code, sku, quantity, status) select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status`as`lg`join`catalog_product_entity`as`prd `on((`lg`.`product_id`=`prd`.`entity_id`)))`
but as soon we run import that field in admin goes empty again.
we have tried to fix and change under inventory and source etc but nothing is working.
we have asked stock in the channel support and they advised nothing is wrong from there side and there plugin is working fine everywhere else and it is to do with something in our magento.

Comment: Did you try bin/magento indexer:reindex command?

Comment: yes and plenty other solutions in google and stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Take DB backup and run below query

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))
```

**after that run below commands.**

php bin/magento in:rein

php bin/magento c:f